# How can I get the url parameters that I just requested in cURL?

Tags: url, curl, url-parameters, http-put

I made a PUT request in cURL and got a OK response.
I want to get the url parameters that I just passed because I want to know what the right parameters look like, so I used '--trace-ascii' option. but I can't find parameters in the trace file.

Can anyone please point out what I should try?
below is my curl request command and the trace file.

```
curl -X PUT {BASE_URL} \
 -H 'Authorization: {AUTH_KEY}' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '{
   "commands": [
     { "id": 0, "info": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
     { "id": 0, "info": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
     { "id": 0, "info": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }
   ]
 }' \
 --trace-ascii debug.dump
```

```
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/json
content-length: 74
date: Sat, 18 Sep 2021 23:34:17 GMT
x-amzn-requestid: ...
x-runtime: 0.123112
x-jets-prewarm-count: 0
x-jets-base64: no
x-amz-apigw-id: ...
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=...
x-jets-call-count: 119
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
via: 1.1 ....cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: ...
x-amz-cf-id: ...
```

Comment: Using HTTP 1.1 instead of letting curl speak http2 would make your life easier here. The `--http1.1` option will do that. HTTP 2 is a binary protocol, so leaving out non-ascii data doesn't leave you with much.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for your answer. I used --http1.1 option but the trace file looks just the same. Is there any other way to check the url when I use http1.1 ?

Comment: The question only includes the response. You should also have the request in your logs; that's where you want to look for the data that was sent. That said, I personally use `-v` rather than `--trace`, so I don't have personal experience with the latter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Understood! Your answer helped me a lot. Thank you very much!